# Compiling JavaScript and HTML code in Visual Studio IDE through ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html

I have been through 3 simple tutorials on how to get started with JavaScript using VS 2010 and they all unanimously describe the basic steps of creating a project through `File`, `New`, `Project`, `ASP.NET Empty Web Application` and then adding a JavaScript file through `Add`, `New Item` and finally adding an HTML page to the project.

The contents of my two files are as follows, as described in all basic tutorials, like a HelloWorld program:

**JScrip1.js**

```
function add(a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**HTMLPage1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>My page title!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" />
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("Sum of 3 and 4 = " + add(3, 4));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In all the tutorials, upon doing a right-click on the HTML component and choosing `View in Browser`, it compiles and shows an alert window with the result (`7`) but mine only shows the tab with the title, and a pop-up message saying that `ASP.NET Development Server is running on port 56044`

The page that opens has the following URL: `http://localhost:56044/HTMLPage1.htm`

What am I missing? Why is my html page completely blank?

**RESOLVED** by changing my HTML script to the following, thanks to Jared

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My page title!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert("Sum of 3 and 4 = " + add(3, 4));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have anything in the body other than your javascript, so the page is gonna be blank. Is the alert popping up when you go to the page? What happens when you debug in the browser (F12)? FYI, HTML and Javascript do not compile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the body, I have the `alert` message that should show when I select `View in browser` by right-clicking on the `HTML` component. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer was that `<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" />` needed changed to `<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js"></script>`. Script tags are not self closing. Apparently browsers don't complain and just silently ignore the tag. :P

---

Is your browser blocking popups? If so, you can change the `alert()` command to `console.log()` command. That should be safer. (Press `F12` to open the browsers developer tools and look for a console tab to see the `console.log()` output)

FYI: The console log will also show javascript errors and such. Like if it can't load the JScrip1.js file.

Comment: Thank you. When I do that, nothing appears in the Chrome Console. I choose to view in browser and then do shift+ctrl+i to bring up the developer tools, but nothing is there in the console...

Comment: That sounds like javascript might be getting blocked entirely. Perhaps try in a different browser to see if that might be the case.

Comment: The same outcome: blank page. I selected `Browse with` and then chose `Internet Explorer` but the same result as described in my post. I am confused... When I use the http://www.w3schools.com/js pages to load JS code, it all works, so that probably means my Google Chrome should be OK. Right?

Comment: Here are a couple other small things that I see wrong with your code above.

In the `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. Html 5 does not use this.

in the `<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" />` change to `<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js"></script>`. Script tags are not self closing.

Comment: Also check your file name `JScript1.js`, it might be missing the `t`.

Comment: I just testing by recreating your files and the malformed script tag for  `JScript1.js` seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works now.  I appreciate your detailed replies.